# Analytics API for Reports

Tags: reports-api, analytics-api

I am using Analytics report API for getting report records.I want to limit  the records returned by this API to one record.

Endpoint I am using is : /services/data/v34.0/analytics/reports/reportId .It will return first 2000 records of that report.But I want only first record of report.Is it possible? Or Please suggest some workaround for this.

Thanks

Comment: this lists reports that were recently viewed by the user. is that what you are trying to accomplish? i mean you want to get the very first item of recently viewed reports?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.Sorry, I posted a wrong endpoint . End-point I am using is /services/data/v34.0/analytics/reports/reportId. This will return records of the report .I want to get first record among them.

Answer (score 1):

you can use "reportFilters" node and filter records based on it or else you can add limit of 1 (limit=1) in the post response.

for reference
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_analytics.meta/api_analytics/sforce_analytics_rest_api_filter_reportdata.htm?search_text=limit